# res.render throwing error Node.JS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, ejs

I've been trying to make this blog, and when it comes to rendering a page it throws, "Res.Render is not a function..."

```
    let express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    methodOV = require("method-override"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    passport = require("passport"),
    pL = require("passport-local"),
    pLM = require("passport-local-mongoose"),
    User = require("./user.js");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/max");

let maxBlog = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    content: String
});

let Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', maxBlog);

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(methodOV("_method"));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//AUTH

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new pL(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.post("/register", (req, res) =>{
    User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.render('register');
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
           res.redirect("/secret");
        });
    });
});

// LOGIN ROUTES
app.get("/login", (req, res) =>{
   res.render("login"); 
});
//login logic
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/secret",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}) ,(req, res) =>{
});

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
});


const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) =>{
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    } else {
      res.redirect("/login");
    }
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.redirect("/home");
});

app.get("/home", (req,res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/blog", (req,res) => {
    Blog.find({},(err,res) => {
        if (err){
            res.send("An unexpected error occured. Please try again later.");
        } else {
            res.render("blog",{blogs:res});
        }
    });
});

app.post("/blog",isLoggedIn,(req,res) => {
    Blog.create({
        title: req.body.t,
        author: req.body.a,
        content: req.body.c
    }), (err,create) => {
        if (err){
            res.send("There was an error. Try again later.");
        } else {
            res.render("blogs");
        }
    };
});

app.get("/blog:id",(req,res) => {
    Blog.findById(req.params.id,(err,find) => {
        if (err){
            res.send("An error occured. Please try again later.");
        } else {
            res.render("show",{blog:find});
        }
    });
});

app.put("/blogs:id",isLoggedIn,(req,res) => {
    Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,({
        content: req.body.c,
        author: req.body.a
    }),(err,update) => {
        if (err){
            res.send("An error occured. Please try again later.");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/blogs"+req.params.id);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Please help! Thank you, Ben This has been bothering for me for a lot of time. It is very weird and all solutions have not worked. I have tried a lot of things and nothing has worked, unfortunately. Thank you so much.

Comment: which function is the one throwing the error?

Comment: Here's the error: TypeError: res.render is not a function
    at Blog.find (/Users/ben/Desktop/ShoeAdict/app.js:92:8)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/ben/Desktop/ShoeAdict/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3911:16)
    at /Users/ben/Desktop/ShoeAdict/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /Users/ben/Desktop/ShoeAdict/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

Comment: sounds like a scope issue. you're trying to call res.render inside another function that also has a res argument which doesnt have a render function

Comment: THX! It worked.

Comment: glad it helped. marking as the correct answer would be great.

Comment: Can't its a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to an argument definition issue.

You can try changing the name of the first function argument to `response`:

```
app.get("/blog", (req,response) => {
    Blog.find({},(err,res) => {
        if (err){
            response.send("An unexpected error occured. Please try again later.");
        } else {
            response.render("blog",{blogs:res});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Note really a scope issue, more of a "hiding" or "redefinition" issue.  Both `req` variables are in scope, but the closer one "hides" the higher level one.  Anyway, this is probably the solution.  FYI, also need to fix `res.send()` in this code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as I created a var named '`res`' but '`res`' was part of '`function(req, res)`' which I already declared. I changed one of them to resp and the problem was solved.